# Использование представления таблицы из SQL

Tags: c#, sql, wpf, visual-studio

В базе данных есть 2 таблицы: `Clients` и `Peoples`. И есть представление `ClientsListView` в нем собраны все нужные мне поля из этих двух таблиц.
[image: ClientsListView]

Я добавил это представление в "Источники данных". Перетянул поля на форму. Создался `DataSet` и `TableAdapter`. Дынные отображаются. Их даже можно изменить в соответствующих `TextBox`. Но как сохранить изменения?
Направьте меня, как добавлять/изменять/удалять данные используя `TableAdapter` для этого `ClientsListView`.

Я так понял, что напрямую в `ClientsListView` добавить данные нельзя. Что делать? Сначала добавлять в `Peoples`, а потом в `Clients`?

Comment: Вообще да. Обычно составные view не редактируемые. Как база догадается куда и в каком порядке что писать. Некоторые СУБД позволяют написать на view триггера в которых собственно руками и написать insert в обе таблицы. Если триггеров нет - то только руками на клиенте как вы и сказали

Comment: _"используя TableAdapter"_ -- это SqlDataAdapter? если да, то для сохранения данных в бд надо вызвать SqlDataAdapter.Update(DataTable) или .Update(DataSet)

Comment: для обычного TableAdapter таблицы в БД - да. Для представления - такого метода нет.

Comment: _"Что делать?"_ -- например хранимую процедуру. в нее предавать изменения. а из нее в таблицы.

Comment: соотв. статья из MSDN:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/ms180800(v=sql.100).aspx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ClientsListView` это по сути именованный запрос типа `SELECT` туда нельзя ничего добавлять. Почитайте про представления в базах данных. Хотя бы в [Википедии](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9F%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B4%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5_%28%D0%B1%D0%B0%D0%B7%D1%8B_%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8B%D1%85%29).

> Сначала добавлять в Peoples, а потом в Clients?

Добавлять данные напрямую в таблицы тоже не есть хорошо. Лучше используйте [хранимые процедуры](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/ms345415%28v=sql.120%29.aspx). Это сразу предотвратит массу проблем.

Comment: Ок. Создал я хранимые процедуры. Я так полагаю 2 шт. или можно одну? Выполнил их/ее и потом просто вызвал обновление `ClientsListViewTableAdapter.Fill()` ?

Comment: Если данные в обеих таблицах связаны, то есть смысл добавлять данные в обе таблицы в одной процедуре. Сначала в главную, потом в подчинённую. После вызова хранимых процедур просто обновите данные полученные из представления. Если всё сделано правильно, должно получиться.